# How does a vector space $V$ act on the polynomial ring $\text{Sym}(V^{\ast})$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $V^{\ast}$ its dual. How does $V$ act on $\text{Sym}(V^{\ast})$?

Choosing a basis $e_1, \ldots , e_n$ for $V$ and the dual basis $e_1^{\ast}, \ldots , e_n^{\ast}$, it seems natural to say that $e_i\cdot e_j^{\ast}=\delta_{ij}$ the Kronecker delta. But how does $e_i$ act on an arbitrary polynomial in the dual variables?

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is over the field $k$, you should compare your situation to the point $a \in k^n$ acting on a polynomial $p \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Here the action is evaluation: replace each variable $x_i$ with the coordinate $a_i$. This should tell you that you're doing the right thing in the coordinates you picked, but I think choosing coordinates is unnecessary to answer this question (or at least you should answer it more abstractly before picking coordinates).

An arbitrary element of $\mathrm{Sym}(V^*)$ may be split into graded parts which are either a constant, or a product of linear functionals $f_1 \cdots f_d$. The action of $v \in V$ on $f_1 \cdots f_d$ should be $f_1(v) \cdots f_d(v)$. Now extend this action linearly.